# Magento add custom value in product object for checkout cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer, addtocart

I want to add two variable in specific product using observer event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add`.
These two variable are use in `checkout/cart` page for display prupose.

Following `config.xml`.

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
        <observers>
         <test_deliverydate_cart_add>
          <class>Test_Deliverydate_Model_Observer</class>
           <method>logCartAdd</method>
         </test_deliverydate_cart_add>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
</events>
```

Following `Observer.php`

```
public function logCartAdd($event)
{

    Mage::getModel('core/session')->setProductToShoppingCart(
        new Varien_Object(array(
            'productId' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('product'),
            'rentalDays' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('rentalDays'),
            'deliveryDate' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('delivery_date'),
        ))
    );
}
```

Following `test-deliverydate.xml`

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" template="test/deliverydate/bookingdate.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Following `bookingdate.phtml`

```
<?php 
    $bookedProductDetail = Mage::getModel('core/session')->getProductToShoppingCart() ;
    $productSku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($bookedProductDetail->getData('productId'))->getSku();
    $rendDays = $bookedProductDetail->getData('rentalDays');

    $bookedDate = $bookedProductDetail->getData('deliveryDate');
    $bookedDate = strtotime($bookedDate);
    $bookedDate = date('Y-m-d', $bookedDate);

    <p> <?php echo $productSku; ?> </p>
    <p> <?php echo $rendDays; ?> </p>
    <p> <?php echo $bookedDate; ?> </p>
?>
```

When I add multiple products at that time last product's detail like : `$rendDays`, `$bookedDate` showing same for all added products.
Please help me how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We Can use below code for get all post value for perticullar `product`.

```
$quote = $observer->getQuote();
    $quote_items = $quote->getItemsCollection();
    foreach ($quote_items as $item)
    {
        if ($item instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item) 
        {
            $infoBuyRequest = $item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
            $buyRequest = new Varien_Object(unserialize($infoBuyRequest->getValue()));
        } 
        else if ($item instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item) 
        {
            $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($item->getProductOptions());
        }
        $buyRequest->getData('product');
        $buyRequest->getData('rentalDays');
        $buyRequest->getData('delivery_date');
    }
```

We can get all data of `product`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like

```
 $cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
        ->getQuote()
        ->getAllItems();
```

Then

```
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $rentalDays = $_product->getData('rentalDays');
    // then do something with it
    echo $rentalDays . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: may be this isn't work because i want update product value before add to cart so that `$cartItems` may be empty.